# how do I map this?

Tags: nhibernate

I am sure I am stupid (which some arrogant clerk at my bank just explained to me) but I don´t get how to map this:

lets say I have a table tbl_products with a ID column
and a tbl_language with a ID column
and my problem: a tbl_product_texts without any id of its own but a product_id and a language_id (and a lot of texts in a couple of languages)

do I have to add a ID column to my table (which is ugly) or can nhibernate keep track of that in private somehow and is this kind of datamodel conceptually wrong or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Product has a one-to-many relationship with ProductText, so you would model Text as a collection on your Products class. You tbl_products_text should have a primary key. You don't state what database you're using but my approach would be to use a surrogate primary key (identifier) and a unique constraint on product_id, language_id. You do not need to take that step to get NHibernate working if you're not managing the texts in your application.

A first pass at your Product class would look like:

```
public class Product
{
    public IList<ProductText> ProductTexts { get; set; }
    public string GetTextForLanguage(int languageId) { ... }
}
```

Comment: thats what I did; added a primary key to the product_text table but it feels somewhat ugly since it is only there for nhibernate

Answer (score 0):

If your trying what I think your trying then You set up a many-to-many mapping between tbl_Products and tbl_language. In the mapping just let nHibernate know which table serves as the link, nHibernate is clever enough to work it out.

https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/collections.html

So in the Products mapping (presuming you want a collection of Languages):

```
<bag name="nameOfLanguageCollection" table="tbl_product_texts">
  <key column="productID" /> <-- Name of ProductID col in tbl_product_texts
  <many-to-many class="LanguageClass" column="language_id" />  <-- name of languageid in   tbl_product_texts 
</bag>
```

I *think* that's right. Can't check now.